# Incorrect syntax near 'cast'

Tags: t-sql

Can't figure out why I get the error

> substring(cast(CASE WHEN l.assigned IS
>   NOT NULL THEN l.assigned ELSE
>   l2.assigned END), 0, 17) as [TEST1]

UPDATED:

The original line I was trying to tweak is the following...wanted to take out that convert because I don't want that format for the datetime:

> , else substring(convert(varchar,
>   cast(CASE WHEN l.assigned IS NOT NULL
>   THEN l.assigned ELSE l2.assigned END
>   as datetime), 126), 0, 17) end) as
>   varchar(20)) as [TEST1]

Also I tried this which I forgot to mention

> substring(cast(CASE WHEN l.assigned IS
>   NOT NULL THEN l.assigned ELSE
>   l2.assigned as datetime END), 0, 17)
>   as [TEST1]

Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an error because you didn't specify a data-type as detailed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). The syntax goes something like this:

```
select cast('1/1/1911' as datetime)
```

You can more simply express your query using [isnull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) (or [coalesce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)) and [left](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx). Keep in mind that unless you're looking for a specific datetime format, you can just do the following:

```
select left(isnull(l.assigned,l2.assigned),17) as [TEST1]
```

Comment: ok so the original syntax was the following.  I needed to strip out the convert...because I don't want that format added:   else substring(convert(varchar, cast(CASE WHEN l.assigned IS NOT NULL THEN l.assigned ELSE l2.assigned END as datetime), 126), 0, 17)  end)
    as varchar(20)) as [TEST1]

Comment: datatype is datetime for those

Comment: So why are you casting to `datetime`? Might help if you add some example data and desired results.

Comment: awesome, thanks for the cleaner code tip:  left(cast(isnull(l.assigned,l2.assigned) as datetime),17) as [TEST1]

Comment: yea I know, I just dove into this pile of sql to fix something...probably doesn't need the cast

Answer (score 1):

`CAST` needs an `AS datatype` that appears to be missing.

e.g.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CAST(
         CASE WHEN 'foo' IS NOT NULL THEN 'foo' ELSE 'FOO' END AS VARCHAR(100))
       , 0, 17) AS [TEST1]
```

You can also use `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` to shorten your code a bit.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CAST(COALESCE(l.assigned,l2.assigned) AS VARCHAR(100)), 0, 17) 
                                                                       AS [TEST1]
```

Comment: oh I had as datetime and that threw a fit also

Answer (score 0):

To what data type you are casting? See reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

You are missing 'as' clause and data type.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast it to a type.

[msdn: CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)